# MsalService / PublicClientApplication is null when trying to logout

Tags: azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

**Problem at High Level**

I have an Angular application that successfully connects to an Azure AD application for authentication. There are no problems with this at all so far. The issue is when I am trying to perform a **logout** function. And I think the issue stems from how I've instantiated the MSAL library in my Angular application.

**Background and Code**

Below is part of the code from my **app.component.ts**. There is a configuration service which reads a local JSON file for information like Azure clientID, applicationID, etc. This is part of the **JsonConfigService**. once NgInit runs, we also get information from our **CompanyApi** which provides information such as the name of the logged in user, their name, etc., and displays it on a header that exists throughout the application (and, thus, it is in the **app.component.ts** file). This header has a hamburger menu, populated by the JSON below, should be inituitive.

```
import { MsalService } from '@azure/msal-angular';
import { JsonConfigService } from 'companylib/common-ng/common';
import { HamburgerItem } from 'companylib/common-ng/app-header';
...

private _securedApplication : IPublicClientApplication = null;
private appSettings: IAppSettings = null;

   constructor( private _cfgSvc: JsonConfigService<IAppSettings>,
               private _headerSvc: HeaderDetailsService
                private _companyApi: CompanyApi
                private _msalAuthService: MsalService) {     
                   
           this._securedApplication = _msalAuthService.instance;
    }
...
    public ngOnInit() {
        this._cfgSvc.config.subscribe(cfg => {
            this.appSettings = cfg;
        });

        this._companyApi.getUserDetails().subscribe(details => {
            this._headerSvc.updateUser(details.nameFull, details.pictureUrl);

            if (this.appSettings) {
                this.title = this.appSettings.title;
                this._headerSvc.updateHeader({
                    title: this.appSettings.title,
                    environment: this.appSettings.environment,
                    version: this.appSettings.version,
                    menuItems: [
                        {
                            path: '/',
                            text: 'Home'
                        }, 
                        {
                            path: 'AdminPage',
                            text: 'Administration Page'
                        }, 
                        {
                            hrule: true,
                            actionText: 'Logout',
                            action: this.logoff
                        }

                    ],
                });
            };
        });
    }

...


logoff() { 
        this._securedApplication.logoutRedirect();
    }
```

**Issue When Ran:**

If I put a breakpoint on **NgInit()**, I can confirm that **_msalAuthService** and the **instance** property both have an object in them. Great. But, when I click on the Hamburger link for Logout(), **this._securedApplication** is undefined. There is no other code in this class that deletes **this._securedApplication**. Again, the clientid, etc., are all fine. Valid tokens are passed and I can see the network traffic.

**Where I Think the Problem Lies**

In order to accommodate reading in from the configuration file, the MsalModule and assorted modules are loaded in the **Providers** section of the **app.module.ts** file. It looks something like this:

```
**app.module.ts** (abbreviated)

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    ...
    CompanyCommonModule,
    AppHeaderModule,
    ToastrModule.forRoot(),
    ...
    NgbModule
  ],
  providers: [
    { 
      provide: APP_INITIALIZER,  
      useFactory: (auth: AuthService) => () => auth.Load(), 
      deps: [AuthService], 
      multi: true },
    { provide: DefaultJsonConfigFactory, useExisting: DefaultSettingsFactory },
    { provide: MappableTokenProviderService, useExisting: ResourceIdAdditionalHeaderService },
    {
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS,
      useClass: MsalInterceptor,
      multi: true
    },
    mlCommonHttpInterceptorProviders,
    { 
      provide: HTTP_INTERCEPTORS, 
      useClass: AdditionalHeadersInterceptor, 
      multi: true 
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INSTANCE,
      useFactory: MSALInstanceFactory, 
      deps: [AuthService]        
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_INTERCEPTOR_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALInterceptorConfigFactory,
      deps: [AuthService] 
    },
    {
      provide: MSAL_GUARD_CONFIG,
      useFactory: MSALGuardConfigFactory,
      deps: [AuthService] 
    },
    MsalService,
    MsalGuard,
    MsalBroadcastService,
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent, MsalRedirectComponent ]
...

and some exported functions: 
export function  MSALInstanceFactory(_authService: AuthService): IPublicClientApplication {

  return new PublicClientApplication(_authService.GetConfiguration());  

}

 export function MSALInterceptorConfigFactory(_authService: AuthService): MsalInterceptorConfiguration {
  
  return {
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    protectedResourceMap : _authService.protectedResources
  };
}

export function MSALGuardConfigFactory(_authService: AuthService): MsalGuardConfiguration {
  return { 
    interactionType: InteractionType.Redirect,
    authRequest: _authService.loginRequest
  };
}
```

It appears to be working just fine, with the configuration set correctly. I just don't have a reference to what I thought was an injected variable.

***What have I done wrong here, and is there a better way to implement this?***